# Link tg://user?id=... rendered as plain text

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Users `A` and `B`, start my Telegram bot with command `/start`.

To `A` the bot sends the message

`<a href="tg://user?id={B.user_id}">B</a>`

To `B` the bot sends the message

`<a href="tg://user?id={A.user_id}">A</a>`

This way I want user to be able to contact each other.`B` receives working link to `A` profile, `A` receives just plain text "B".

What might be the reason that `<a href="tg://user?id={B.user_id}">B</a>` is rendered as plain text rather than a working link?

- I thought maybe it is because `B` does not have @username. To test this I created test user `C` without @username, started the bot and it sent `<a href="tg://user?id={C.user_id}">C</a>` to `A`, `A` received working link to `C`.
- Maybe `B` blocked my bot? I blocked bot with my test user `C`, the bot sent `A` a link to `C`, and `A` received working link.
- [According to documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options)

> "These mentions are only guaranteed to work if the user has contacted
> the bot in the past"

But both `A` and `B` have contacted my bot with command `/start`.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say why the link isn't rendering properly, is there anymore information in the bot log?

It is worth noting there are other criteria for this to work.

> These mentions are only guaranteed to work if the user has contacted
> the bot in the past, has sent a callback query to the bot via an
> inline button or is a member in the group where he was mentioned.

So are `A` and `C` members of a group that `B` isn't?

Anyhow you could try the links as markdown rather than HTML. e.g.

```
[B](tg://user?id={B.user_id})
```

Answer (score 0):

Account B has a block on forwarded messages in privacy settings.